# vb6 project fpSpr60.ocx missing

Tags: vb6, ocx

I got an old vb6 project which I am trying to get going.

I have installed visual studio 6, installed vb6 service pack 6 and the update for service pack 6.

However when I open the project I keep getting the error:

```
fpSpr60.ocx could not be loaded
```

I figured out with google this has todo with fpspread but I also find this should be included inside vb6. 
Does anyone have an idea where to look for?

Comment: Google tells me that fpspr60.ocx appears to be The Farpoint Spreadsheet component.. https://www.componentsource.com/product/farpoint-spread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a third-party OCX which is not shipped with VB6. You must obtain it and install it separately.

(I have no association with the company.)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand, I thought was a part of vb6.